# Can i have access to my WordPress Website again?

Tags: urls

I have a problem with my website. I deleted, unintentionally, parts of my WordPress URL. My URL at the beginning was `www.e-cooking.pingfiles.fr`, and i deleted "pingfiles" unintentionally.

I want to know if it is possible to have access back to my site so that I can finish my work.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look in your database in the wp_options table. There are two rows in the table that are relevant: look for `siteurl` and `home` - one or both of them will need to be edited, and updated to the correct url.

Alternatively you can edit your wp-config.php file and add the following lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.e-cooking.pingfiles.fr');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.e-cooking.pingfiles.fr');
```

I got my information from the Codex, [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).